# flexslider displays images below each other

Tags: drupal-7, flexslider

I have a strange issue with flexslider. On my development server, it works perfectly. On my production server, it just displays the images below each other and you can see that no jquery/javascript is loaded for flexslider, also, no css.

The development and production environments are exactly the same, as in exactly. They have the same jquery version, the same modules, the same version of drupal 7, the sames css, theme etc.

Please help.

Example of Problem:

**1 - Development Server**
[image: Development Server]

**2 - Production Server**
[image]

**EDIT: SOLVED**

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the problem was that the permissions of my flexslider folder was restricted, so my flexslider.js was not loaded. Fixed the permissions, now it works fine. Maybe this will help someone with similar issues :)

Answer (score 0):

Woothemes just released Flexslider version 2.3.0 on Feb. 11, 2015. There seems to be a bug when using it with the Drupal Flexslider 7.2.0-alpha3 module version and the views plugin. It throws a

```
typeerror: $(...).flexslider is not a function
```

error. 
Woothemes [Flexslider 2.2.2](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/archive/version/2.2.2.zip) works perfectly though.